# Insert into as select in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-insert, amazon-redshift

I have a table emp -

```
empno int(5) identity(1,1),
ename varchar(50) default '-0',
deptname varchar(50) default '-0'
```

When I use the statement -

```
insert into emp(ename, deptname) select ename, deptname from emp1;
```

I am getting all the values from emp1, but the null values are not substituted with `-0` but rather with `null`.

What is the reason ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Intended Behaviour

According to the [Redshift documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html#r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW-parameters):

> DEFAULT *default_expr*
>
> [...]
>
> The *default_expr* expression is used in any INSERT operation that does not specify a value for the column. If no default value is specified, the default value for the column is null.

So when you execute `insert into emp(ename, deptname)` then you do specify values for both those columns: if nothing else, they are `NULL`. Only if you leave out the columns, the default values will be used. So `default` values are only really useful if you insert values directly:

```sql
insert into emp(ename, deptname) values('some_ename', default);
insert into emp(ename, deptname) values(default, 'some_deptname');
insert into emp(ename, deptname) values(default, default);
```

Which would give:

```
select * from emp order by empno;
 empno |   ename    |   deptname
-------+------------+---------------
     1 | some_ename | -0
     2 | -0         | some_deptname
     3 | -0         | -0
(3 rows)
```

---

## Possible Solutions to Your Problem

#### Option 1: Two `INSERT` Statements

Pro: You don't need to know about the actual default values 
Con: This might be tedious if you have many columns

```sql
insert into emp(ename) select ename from emp1 where deptname is null;
insert into emp(deptname) select deptname from emp1 where ename is null;
```

#### Option 2: Use `COALESCE`

Pro: One query to `default` them all
Con: You will have to know the default values

```sql
insert into emp(ename, deptname)
    select
        coalesce(ename, '-0')    as ename
      , coalesce(deptname, '-0') as deptname
    from
        emp1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table_name(column_list) (select column_list from table_name);
```

make sure you don't have any columns whose name is like datatype

ex : timestamp is datatype but by mistake if you have created column name using datatype use alias name in select query like
timestamp as Timestamp_t